# DELETE+INSERT and SELECT in one SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

I can't seem to perform a `DELETE`, `INSERT` and `SELECT` in one SPARQL query. I need to get the results of what was changed etc. in a very complex `WHERE` clause.

e.g.

```
SELECT ?name
DELETE {?someone :name: ?name}
INSERT {?someone :name ?newName}
WHERE {
    ...
}
```

Any ideas how to make it work, without repeating the `WHERE` calculation (which would be very inefficient)?

I get a syntax error upon `DELETE` (Expecting `WHERE` etc.)

Comment: There is no SELECT clause in SPARQL 1.1 Update. The syntax is `DELETE quadpattern INSERT quadpattern WHERE ...`. See https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-update-20130321/#deleteInsert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SELECT clause in SPARQL 1.1 Update. The syntax is

```
 DELETE quadpattern 
 INSERT quadpattern 
 WHERE ...
```

See https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-update-20130321/#deleteInsert

Comment: I hope it is introduced in future. Currently I have to perform the same `WHERE` calculation twice. Once for a select, and another time again for the `DELETE` and `INSERT`.